# Counting children rows with CodeIgniter Active Record not returning all results

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a locations table in my database. Locations may have have parents or children within the table. See table below:

```
location_id | location_parent_id | location_name | location_level
------------+--------------------+---------------+---------------
 1          | 0                  | South Africa  | 0
------------+--------------------+---------------+---------------
 2          | 1                  | Gauteng       | 1
------------+--------------------+---------------+---------------
 3          | 1                  | Western Cape  | 1
------------+--------------------+---------------+---------------
 4          | 2                  | Johannesburg  | 2
------------+--------------------+---------------+---------------
 5          | 4                  | Sandton       | 3
------------+--------------------+---------------+---------------
 6          | 4                  | Hilbrow       | 3
```

I am using Codeigniter's active records class and would like to select all locations. Each row should have the location's parent name and the number of children that location has. I've managed to almost get what I'm looking for with this code:

```
$locations = $this->db->select('count(C.location_parent_id) as children_count ,L.location_id, L.location_name, L.location_status, L.location_level, P.location_name as parent_name')
            ->from('locations L')
            ->join('locations P', 'L.location_parent_id=P.location_id','left')
            ->join('locations C', 'C.location_parent_id=L.location_id')
            ->group_by('C.location_parent_id')
            ->get();
```

Output:

```
ID | NAME         | PARENT        | CHILDREN COUNT| LEVEL
---+--------------+---------------+---------------+------
 1 | South Africa |               | 2             | 0
---+--------------+---------------+---------------+------
 2 | Gauteng      | South Africa  | 2             | 1
---+--------------+---------------+---------------+------
 3 | Johannesburg | Gauteng       | 2             | 2
---+--------------+---------------+---------------+------
```

So it would appear that I am only getting rows that has chidren but I need the rows that dont have children as well. Any ideas on what I am missing would be great?

*EDIT* Expecting:

```
ID | NAME               | PARENT        | CHILDREN COUNT | LEVEL
---+--------------------+---------------+----------------+-------
 1 | South Africa       |               | 2              | 0
---+--------------------+---------------+----------------+-------
 2 | Gauteng            | South Africa  | 1              | 1
---+--------------------+---------------+----------------+-------
 3 | Western Cape       | South Africa  | 0              | 1
---+--------------------+---------------+----------------+-------
 4 | Johannesburg       | Gauteng       | 2              | 2
---+--------------------+---------------+----------------+-------
 5 | Sandton            | Johannesburg  | 0              | 3
---+--------------------+---------------+----------------+-------
 6 | Hilbrow            | Johannesburg  | 0              | 3
```

Comment: what is you expected result set ?

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid - I've added an edit with the expected reults

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured it out. My **group_by** statement was wrong and I needed to **LEFT** join the children, The new statement is

```
$locations = $this->db->select('count(C.location_parent_id) as children_count ,L.location_id, L.location_name, L.location_status, L.location_level, P.location_name as parent_name')
        ->from('locations L')
        ->join('locations P', 'L.location_parent_id=P.location_id','left')
        ->join('locations C', 'C.location_parent_id=L.location_id','left')
        ->group_by('L.location_id')
        ->get();
```